# How to match a <br> if nothing is infront

Tags: php, html

Problem, I get more linebreaks that I want in my html_to_bbcode function.

Case: I got a random text like this.

```
test<br>
<br>
again something<br>
```

so the output should be like

```
test

again somthing
```

and not like it now

```
test


again some text
 `
```

I used to do a

```
$text = str_replace("<br>","\n",$text);
```

but It shouldnt replace the `<br>` with an `\n` if there is a text before that because else it simply do \n\n

Edited the case and expected outcome

Solution was like @Dirk Horsten posted:

```
$text2 = str_replace("<br />","<br>",$text);
$text = str_replace("<br>","",preg_replace("/^<br>/","\n",$text2));
```

I needed to swap the `<br />` in my code to `<br>` cause else resulted in the warning 
preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '>'

Comment: check the answer and say me whether your  problem solved?

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: What output do you want if there are two successive lines with only a `<br>`? What if a `<br>` occurs in the middle of a line?

Comment: @DirkHorsten , your case should never happend since its safed correct first time the user creates the post, my problem only occours on editing

Comment: Can you explain what _saved correct_ means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements go beyond string replacement. I advice regular expressions.

If you want to replace subsequent `<br>` by a single \n:

```
$text = $text = preg_replace("(/(<br>\s)+/m)","\n",$text);
```

If you only want to replace the `<br>` at the beginning of a line, try this

```
$text = $text = preg_replace("/^<br>/","\n",$text);
```

but then the `<br>` inside or at the end of a line survive, so probably you need

```
$text = $text = str_replace("<br>","",preg_replace("/^<br>/","\n",$text));
```

*Disclaimer: I dont have php installed so this is not tested. There fore I made it a community wiki, so anyone can edit it*

Comment: Cheers, i struggled with this problem for several days , thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

almost you have found the solution. Try this

```
<?php
$text="test<br>
<br>
again something<br>";
$text = str_replace("<br>","\n",$text);
echo nl2br($text);

?>
```

Comment: your code should give me the double line break which i dont want

Comment: @kobiiiiii: then what you want?

Comment: If you again watch the text example , it should replace the first <br> with "nothing" and the second one with the linebreak (\n) and the 3rd<br> again with nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try  following code,

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
            '/[a-z]{1}<br>/',
            function ($matches) {
                return $matches[0].'\n';
            }, $st);
 echo $str;
```